# Speeding Up Access 2007 Text Searches

Tags: full-text-search, performance, ms-access-2007

I have a database for tracking customer purchases over history.  One of my forms allows you to search for a customer name, and a subform displays all recent purchases.

I have a total of 474 customer records.  I am tracking a total of 2119 purchase records.  The BE and FE are already split, which may be slowing things down, but is needed for distribution and to help control file size.

I am simply using the search box located at the bottom of the form by default.

Is there anything I can do to speed up this search function?  I would be ok with it waiting for complete input rather than searching with every character change.

Comment: I just did some research on this, and there don't appear to be any configuration options for this built-in functionality. Are the fields in question indexed? If not, you might try indexing the most commonly searched fields.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  My indexes do appear to be set up properly.  Should I just get off my butt and write my own search function?  I would have no idea where to start.

Comment: I think that if the built-in function doesn't work adequately for you, you have to write your own. What happens when you Ctrl-F within a particular field? I know that's not the same as the search you're using (where you don't have to specify the field), but it may help you put off rolling your own search (not that it's horridly difficult, just kind of tedious).

Comment: I can do that I guess...  I'll want to put a macro behind the field so Ctrl+F executes on field entry.

Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: That might get annoying if it happens by default. You might try putting it in the doubleclick event. Also, don't use SendKeys, but instead use DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFind .

Comment: what's your current wait time range for searches to return data? is it all local or are the BE/FE on different boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you wish for a way to quickly select customers by name. If this is the case, I believe the best thing for you is a combobox that finds a record on you form. The combobox wizard will do the work for you, simply add a combobox and choose "Find a record on my form" from the options offered.